# Hide Entries in List not created by the user?

Tags: 2013, permissions, custom-list

Is it possible to allow users to create an entry in a list, but not show them entries that others have made?  Some of the data is sensitive and I don't want them to see everyone else's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to allow users to only view the list items they create. Follow the steps below:

- Go to the List Settings
- Then to the Advanced Settings
- Then under the **Item-level Permissions** section select the *Read items that were created by the user* radio button.

Note that users with Full Control can still see all items, it is only the users with Contribute access that this setting will apply to.